# regular expression extractor template values in beanshell post processor

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, beanshell

I have extracted valeus from response using regular expression extractor and defined template as $1$,$2$, i now want to use those values in beanshell post processor. How do i do that.
I am unable to fetch those valeus in my beanshell editor.
[image]

[image]

[image]

How do i import $1$ to variable x and $2$ to variable Y into beanshell postprocessor.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Change first 2 lines of your Beanshell code to be:

```
name=vars.get("outlet_g1");
email=vars.get("outlet_g2");
```

Going forward I would suggest using [Debug Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) and [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener combination so you could see all the variables originated from the Regular Expression Extractor along with their values. See [How to Debug your Apache JMeter Script](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script) guide for more details